# ACL (Access Control List) Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

How can i edit add permision table from template form.[image] I want to create Access Control List using permission table, similar to the image. Where I want to display permission form with a checkbox. On the check, permission should bbe given to that user and group. Please help me to create ACL.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a django inbuilt table **auth_permissions** (all the permition listed in it) and for group permission use **auth_group_permission**. and for create permission for every model use a

class Meta:
    permissions = (
        ('permission_code(unique)', 'description'),
    )